# Pygame, sounds don't play

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I'm trying to play sound files (.wav) with pygame but when I start it I never hear anything.
This is the code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
sounda= pygame.mixer.Sound("desert_rustle.wav")

sounda.play()
```

I also tried using channels but the result is the same

Comment: Probably moot for the original poster, but whoever finds this with a search, avoid those solutions with no sleep time or fixed sleep time.  Look at my answer that sleeps, but only while the music/sound is playing.  That is what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code plays `desert_rustle.wav` quite fine on my machine (Mac OSX 10.5, Python 2.6.4, pygame 1.9.1).  What OS and Python and pygame releases are you using?  Can you hear the `.wav` OK by other means (e.g. `open` on a Mac's terminal or `start` on a Windows console followed by the filename/path to the `.wav` file) to guarante the file is not damaged?  It's hard to debug your specific problem (which is not with the code you give) without being able to reproduce it and without having all of these crucial details.

Answer (score 23):

For me (on Windows 7, Python 2.7, PyGame 1.9) I actually have to remove the pygame.init() call to make it work or if the pygame.init() stays to create at least a screen in pygame.

My example:

```
import time, sys
from pygame import mixer

# pygame.init()
mixer.init()

sound = mixer.Sound(sys.argv[1])
sound.play()

time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: The `time.sleep(5)` was the solution (like answered by VagosLabrou).

Comment: Wow, letting pygame.init() away solved it for me. Incredible!

Comment: removing pygame.init did it for me as well

Comment: Is the sound you are playing exactly 5 seconds long?  You should have a loop, as in my answer, to keep the thread long enough to play the entire sound.

Answer (score 13):

sounda.play() returns an object which is necessary for playing the sound. With it you can also find out if the sound is still playing:

```
channela = sounda.play()
while channela.get_busy():
   pygame.time.delay(100)
```

Comment: This was the fix for me; none of the tutorials online show anything about waiting for the sound file to actually finish playing. As it is, if you run a Python script on the command line, the script will exit before the sound actually has a chance to play!

Other solutions that just suggest adding a sleep() aren't as useful if you want the script to allow playback of any length of file.

Answer (score 9):

I had no sound from playing mixer.Sound, but **it started to work after i created the window**, this is a minimal example, just change your filename, run and press UP key to play:

```
WAVFILE = 'tom14.wav'
import pygame
from pygame import *
import sys

mixer.pre_init(frequency=44100, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=4096)
pygame.init()
print pygame.mixer.get_init() 
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((400,400),0,32) 

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:                                                    
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_ESCAPE:
                 pygame.quit()
                 sys.exit()
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                s = pygame.mixer.Sound(WAVFILE)
                ch = s.play()
                while ch.get_busy():
                    pygame.time.delay(100)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 6):

What you need to do is something like this:

```
 import pygame
 import time

 pygame.init()
 pygame.mixer.init()
 sounda= pygame.mixer.Sound("desert_rustle.wav")

 sounda.play()
 time.sleep (20)
```

The reason I told the program to sleep is because I wanted a way to keep it running without typing lots of code. I had the same problem and the sound didn't play because  the program closed immediately after trying to play the music.

In case you want the program to actually do something just type all the necessary code but make sure it will last long enough for the sound to fully play.

Comment: Do you want to keep the program idle for 20 seconds if the sound is only 2 seconds?  Check my answer please.

Comment: Erase all these posts that need  time() and sleep() please. You CAN try some sort of (incorrect

Answer (score 4):

```
import pygame, time


pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()

sounda= pygame.mixer.Sound("beep.wav")

sounda.play()
```

`pygame.init()` goes after `mixer.init()`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem under windows 7. In my case I wasn't running the code as Administrator. Don't ask me why, but opening a command line as administrator fixed it for me.

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work. Still i think it is a windows problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is pygame.mixer.music:

```
import pygame.mixer
from time import sleep
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(open("\windows\media\chimes.wav","rb"))
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    sleep(1)
print "done"
```

Answer (score 3):

You missed to wait for the sound to finish. Your application will start playing the sound but will exit immediately.

If you want to play a single *wav* file, you have to initialize the module and create a [`pygame.mixer.Sound()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) object from the file. Invoke [`play()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.play) to start playing the file. Finally, you have to wait for the file to play.

Use [`get_length()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.get_length) to get the length of the sound in seconds and wait for the sound to finish:
(The argument to [`pygame.time.wait()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.wait) is in milliseconds)

```py
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
sounda = pygame.mixer.Sound('desert_rustle.wav')
sounda.play()
pygame.time.wait(int(sounda.get_length() * 1000))
```

Alternatively you can use [`pygame.mixer.get_busy`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.play) to test if a sound is being mixed. Query the status of the mixer continuously in a loop.
In the loop, you need to delay the time by either [`pygame.time.delay`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.delay) or [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick). In addition, you need to handle the events in the application loop. See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) respectively [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.init()
sounda = pygame.mixer.Sound('desert_rustle.wav')
sounda.play()

while pygame.mixer.get_busy():
    pygame.time.delay(10)
    pygame.event.poll()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to re-save your wav file to make sure its frequency info. Or you can record a sound to make sure its frequency,bits,size and channels.(I use this method to solve this problem)

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
import pygame.mixer
from time import sleep
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(open("\windows\media\chimes.wav","rb"))
print ""
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    sleep(1)
print "done"
```

This should work. You just need to add `print ""`and the sound will have
had time to load its self.

Answer (score 0):

I've had something like this happen. Maybe you have the same problem? Try using an absolute path:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
sounda= pygame.mixer.Sound("/absolute_path/desert_rustle.wav")

sounda.play()
```

Where *abslute_path* is obviously replaced with your actual absolute path ;)

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("desert_rustle.wav")
pygame.mixer.Sound.play(sound)
```

This will work on python 3

Answer (score 0):

5 years late answer but I hope I can help someone.. :-)

Firstly, you dont need the "pygame.init()"-line.
Secondly, make a loop and play the sound inside that, or else pygame.mixer will start, and stop playing again immediately.

I got this code to work fine on my Raspberry pi with Raspbian OS.
Note that I used a while-loop that continues to loop the sound forver.

```
import pygame.mixer

pygame.mixer.init()
sounda = pygame.mixer.Sound("desert_rustle.wav")

while True:
    sounda.play()
```

Comment: The "while True:" loop creates multiple instances of the sound playing. It is not equivalent to playing a sound or song once. It's going to max out the gain of your output and significantly lessen the quality of the sounds you play. Use a thread for playing sounds and have sounds play/stop in response to events.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the posts are running all of this at toplevel, which is why the sound may seem to close. The final method will return while the sound is playing, which closes the program/terminal/process (depending on how called).
What you will eventually want is a probably a class that can call either single time playback or a looping function (both will be called, and will play over each other) for background music and single sound effects.

Here is pattern, that uses a different event loop / run context other than Pygame itself, (I am using tkinter root level object and its init method, you will have to look this up for your own use case) once you have either the Pygame.init() runtime or some other, you can call these methods from your own logic, unless you are exiting the entire runtime, each file playback (either single use or looping)

this code covers the init for ONLY mixer (you need to figure our your root context and where the individual calls should be made for playback, at least 1 level inside root context to be able to rely on the main event loop preventing premature exit of sound files, YOU SHOULD NOT NEED TIME.SLEEP() AT ALL (very anti-pattern here).... ALSO whatever context calls the looping forever bg_music, it will probably be some 'level' or 'scene' or similar in your game/app context, when passing from one 'scene' to the next you will probably want to immediately replace the bg_music with the file for next 'scene', and if you need the fine-grained control stopping the sound_effect objects that are set to play once (or N times)....

```
from pygame import mixer

bg_music = mixer.Channel(0)
sound_effects = mixer.Channel(1)

call either of these from WITHIN your inner logic loops


effect1 = mixer.Sound('Sound_Effects/'+visid+'.ogg')
sound_effects.play(effect1, 0)
        
        
sound1 = mixer.sound('path to ogg or wav file')
bg_music.play(sound1, -1) # play object on this channel, looping forever (-1)
```

Answer (score -1):

do this:

```
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("desert_rustle.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
```

I think that your problem is that the file is a WAV file.
It worked for me with an MP3. This will probably work on python 3.6.