# How to play a sound in a "Hello World" Python program (kids class context)

Tags: python

I'm trying to play a sound in a "Hello World" Python program for a children's class. I used the pygame library for that, but the program can't open the sound file. How can I fix this?

```
 import pygame
 pygame.init()
 song = pygame.mixer.Sound('robot.wav')
 song.play()
 print ("Hello, world!")

 Error = song = pygame.mixer.Sound('robot.wav')
 pygame.error: Unable to open file 'robot.wav'
```

Comment: Have you tried giving the absolute path to the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pygame, sounds don't play](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936914/pygame-sounds-dont-play)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, after pygame.init() you need pygame.mixer.init().  Second of all, you can't just load files from anywhere.  For your program to load robot.wav, you either need to put robot.wav **in the same directory as** your program file, or you need to specify the entire path to robot.wav.  C:/MyPrograms/HelloWorld/robot.wav is an example of a file path, if you are using Windows.

It is also possible that the sound file is corrupted or in the wrong format (e.g. not a wav file, even though it is named .wav).

Refer to:

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html

http://www.pygame.org/docs/