# Cannot open wav file or play contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, wav

I'm attempting to blend multiple wav files into a single file. The output plays only silence in windows media player and can't be read in pygame. Here's what I did:

```
oh = scipy.io.wavfile.read('Downloads\\sounds\\OH10.wav')
sns = scipy.io.wavfile.read('Downloads\\sounds\\snshort.wav')
diff = len(oh[1])-len(sns[1])
spacer = np.array([0]*diff)
newsns = np.concatenate([spacer, sns[1]])
x = np.hstack((oh[1], newsns))
scipy.io.wavfile.write('testing.wav', rate=44100, data=x.T)
```

Basically I want two sounds to be combined into one. I added the spacer so that the arrays are of same length.

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)
mixer.init()
mixer.Sound('testing.wav').play()
```

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-306-6be10c568430> in <module>
      3 pygame.init() #turn all of pygame on.
      4 pygame.mixer.init()
----> 5 pygame.mixer.Sound('testing.wav').play()

error: Unable to open file 'testing.wav'
```

Comment: Make sure `testing.wav` is in the same folder as your python file, or learn about _"relative paths in python"_.

Comment: It is in the right folder, the problem is the output array. I do not know much about audio engineering, mainly how arrays are encoded

Comment: Have you tried ogg file format? Or making sure that the wav is uncompressed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936914/pygame-sounds-dont-play