# Python VLC won't play the audio?

Tags: python, audio, pygame, vlc

I'm trying to play an mp3 file using python VLC but it seems like nothing is happening and there is no error message. Below is the code:

```
import vlc
p = vlc.MediaPlayer(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\python\projects\etc\lady_maria.mp3")
p.play()
```

I tried below code as I've read from another post:

```
import vlc
mp3 = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/python/projects/etc/lady_maria.mp3"

instance = vlc.get_default_instance()
media = instance.media_new(mp3)
media_list = instance.media_list_new([mp3])

player = instance.media_player_new()
player.set_media(media)

list_player = instance.media_list_player_new()
list_player.set_media_player(player)
list_player.set_media_list(media_list)
```

I also tried to use pygame mixer but same reason, no sounds, and no error message.

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\python\projects\etc\lady_maria.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
```

All of these do not give an error message so I'm not sure what is going on.. Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could it be Audio Volume?

Comment: @Kingsley I tried the audio but still not working and no error messages... :(

Comment: With the Pygame example - you did wait for the music to play right?  `mixer.music.play()` just *starts* the music playing, then returns immediately. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8415875/1730895

Comment: @Kingsley yes I waited but nothing, with volume 100. Do you recommend any other audio playing library other than vlc and pygame?

Comment: Does that particular mp3 play OK with other software?

Comment: @Kingsley yes, I mean, I can play the mp3 file without any problem. I recently downloaded vlc (since originally I tried to use python vlc), do you think it could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If audio files are playing fine on the system:-

for pygame library adjust volume using:

```
mixer.music.set_volume(1.0)  # float value from 0.0 to 1.0 for volume setting
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for input, I tried this but still, no sound even after setting the volume to 100... Would that be another reason?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was solved as:

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\python\projects\etc\lady_maria.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(5)
```

adding `time.sleep(5)` fixed the problem!

[Pygame, sounds don't play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936914/pygame-sounds-dont-play)

Answer (score 0):

I can't work out what the actual issue is given the code in the OP.  Please try this test code.

```
import pygame
  
WINDOW_WIDTH  = 200
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 200

### initialisation
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )

# Rain sound from: https://www.freesoundslibrary.com/sound-of-rain-falling-mp3/ (CC BY 4.0)
pygame.mixer.music.load( 'rain-falling.mp3' )
pygame.mixer.music.play( loops=-1 )             # loop forever

### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

    # Draw some text
    window.fill( ( 0, 0, 50 ) )
    ms = font.render( str( pygame.time.get_ticks() ), True, ( 255,255,255 ) )
    window.blit( ms, ( 100, 100 ) )
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(30)

pygame.quit()
```

If you download the MP3 from the link in the source, and running this script produces no sound, the issue is with your local machine setup.  In this case perhaps verify you are using a recent version of Python and PyGame.  I've tested this with Python 3.8.2 and PyGame 1.9.6.

I don't think installing [VLC Media Player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) would hurt anything.  This is my daily "go-to" media player.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the help, well this one works just fine!!! I hear the rain noise loud and clear. Now I'm more confused about what I'm doing wrong... ;-(