# playsound plays mp3 file but plays it very quietly

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, logitech, playsound

I am trying to get a simple click tone to play on Pycharm2023/Python3.11/Win7. But the audio file, which when I play it by itself (whether by windows media player or VLC) sounds fine, but in the python script it is very faint I can barely hear it.

I got the mp3 file here: https://pixabay.com/sound-effects/search/metronome/ the very first tone.

```
from playsound import playsound
import time

def print_hi(name):
    while True:
        playsound('click.mp3')
        time.sleep(1)

# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('PyCharm')
```

My speaker is logitech Z407.
Same effect if I just run the script on IDLE too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try playing the file with `Pygame`.  Increase the volume to `1.0`, then `1.2` and test in small increments.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pygame import mixer 
  
# Starting the mixer 
mixer.init() 
  
# Loading the song 
mixer.music.load("song.wav") 
  
# Setting the volume 
mixer.music.set_volume(0.7) 
  
# Start playing the song 
mixer.music.play() 
  
# infinite loop 
while True: 
      
    print("Press 'p' to pause, 'r' to resume") 
    print("Press 'e' to exit the program") 
    query = input("  ") 
      
    if query == 'p': 
  
        # Pausing the music 
        mixer.music.pause()      
    elif query == 'r': 
  
        # Resuming the music 
        mixer.music.unpause() 
    elif query == 'e': 
  
        # Stop the mixer 
        mixer.music.stop() 
        break
```

Comment: for some reason this didn't work for me, by i started looking into pygame based on your suggestion and this solution worked:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64521581/943222

Comment: Ahh, `pygame` probably doesn't support compressed audio.  Similar to `aplay` requiring `.wav` files.  I used it with an alert.wav myself, not mp3.  I've earned myself a lesson in assumption. :-)